# Add content in new row jQuery ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have problem with adding new content in new row. This is my code and I don't know how to display all content in new row.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  showUsers()
});

function showUsers() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "https://barka.foi.hr/WebDiP/2019/materijali/zadace/dz3/userNameSurname.php?all",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(response) {
      $(response).find("user").each(function() {
        var name = $(this).find("name").text();
        $("#imeGet").append(name + "<br>");
        var prezime = $(this).find("surname").text();
        $("#prezimeGet").append(prezime + "<br>");
        var email = $(this).find("email").text();
        $("#emailGet").append(email + "<br>");
        var slika = $(this).find("image").text();
        $("#slikaGet").append(slika + "<br>");
      });
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ime</th>
      <th>prezime</th>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>slika</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td id="imeGet" style="border: 1px solid red;"></td>
      <td id="prezimeGet"></td>
      <td id="emailGet"></td>
      <td id="slikaGet"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<p id="xx"></p>
```

Comment: I would like to have 32 rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the rows like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  showUsers()
});

function showUsers() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "https://barka.foi.hr/WebDiP/2019/materijali/zadace/dz3/userNameSurname.php?all",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(response) {
      $(response).find("user").each(function() {
        var name = $(this).find("name").text();
        var prezime = $(this).find("surname").text();
        var email = $(this).find("email").text();
        var slika = $(this).find("image").text();
        var newUser = "<tr><td style='border: 1px solid red;'>" + name + "</td><td>"
+ prezime + "</td><td>" + email + "</td><td>"  + slika +  "</td></tr>";
        $(".table").append(newUser);
      });
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ime</th>
      <th>prezime</th>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>slika</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
<p id="xx"></p>
```

Comment: Thank you a lot. you saved me

Comment: @Learner12  Glad I was able to help :) If this answered your question, you can accept this answer so your question will be marked as closed/solved. If you don't know how this works, just check https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work#answer-5235